# How to import a dialogflow zip using an API

Tags: c#, dialogflow-es

I've got a C# project and the dialogflow google api reference added in it.

```
using Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2;
```

And I want to know if I can use that to import a zip to my dialogflow agent.

Using the Dialogflow Web Console I can do this:

[image: Dialogflow Console Export and Import]

Would be great if I could achieve this functionality in C# somehow.

Any help / advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd expect that to be a matter of calling [`AgentsClient.ImportAgent`](https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2/latest/api/Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2.AgentsClient.html#Google_Cloud_Dialogflow_V2_AgentsClient_ImportAgent_Google_Cloud_Dialogflow_V2_ImportAgentRequest_Google_Api_Gax_Grpc_CallSettings_), e.g.

```
var zipFile = File.ReadAllBytes("agent.zip");
var zipByteString = ByteString.CopyFrom(zipFile);
var client = AgentsClient.Create();
var request = new ImportAgentRequest
{
    ParentAsProjectName = new ProjectName("[YOUR PROJECT ID]")
    AgentContent = zipByteString
};
var operation = client.ImportAgent(client);
operation.PollUntilCompleted();
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback Mr. Jon ^-^.

Comment: I'm now experiencing this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57486298/how-to-authenticate-google-credentials-for-dialogflow-integration