# How to authenticate Google Credentials for Dialogflow Integration

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, google-authentication

I want to integrate my C# system with Google Dialogflow. 
So I'm trying to use the code Mr. Jon showed me over here:

[How to import a dialogflow zip using an API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57480321/how-to-import-a-dialogflow-zip-using-an-api)

But I'm getting this problem:

> The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are
>   available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the
>   environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined
>   pointing to a file defining the credentials. See
>   https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials
>   for more information.

I've downloaded my Dialogflow Project Service Account Key JSON File.
And I'm trying to use this code to Authenticate:

```
// Some APIs, like Storage, accept a credential in their Create() method.
// Explicitly use service account credentials by specifying the private key file.
GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(theServiceAccountJSONFilePath);
StorageClient storage = StorageClient.Create(credential);
// Make an authenticated API request.
PagedEnumerable<Buckets, Bucket> buckets = storage.ListBuckets(theProjectID);
foreach (Bucket bucket in buckets)
{
    Console.WriteLine(bucket.Name);
}
return null;
```

I got that code from this link: [Setting Up Authentication for Server to Server Production Applications](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production)

Problem is that code runs into this problem for me:

> dialogflow-ixksso@maintest-vskxxy.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not
>   have storage.buckets.list access to project 160007643358.

I am on the free option on my 'Google Cloud Platform'. Maybe the free option doesn't allow authenticating in this way.

I don't have a lot of experience with this, so any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to go into [IAM in the Cloud Console](http://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam) and give that service account the relevant role (e.g. Storage Object Viewer). See if that helps - I can't give more details right now, but if you leave a comment after trying, I'll check later.

Comment: @JonSkeet I've added the 'Storage Admin' role to my service account; and now the authenticate code works 100%, but on "var client = AgentsClient.Create();" I still get a problem. How do I pass the 'GoogleCredential' to that 'AgentsClient'?

Comment: The simplest option is to use the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable so you don't need to load the credential at all. If you really need to load it dynamically, then you can use `var client = new AgentsClientBuilder { TokenAccessMethod = credential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync }.Build()` - see https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/faq.html#how-can-i-use-non-default-credentials-for-grpc-based-apis for miore details.

Comment: @JonSkeet I think I've found a solution. My 'AgentClient' seems to 'Create' now. But I'm getting a new problem after that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57495017/dialogflow-c-sharp-integration-the-type-initializer-for-dialogflow-v2-agent. This is becoming a real struggle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in comments, the simplest way in most cases is to specify the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable to refer to the JSON file.

If you need to load the credential some other way, you can use the client builder to specify credentials quite flexibly:

#### From an ICredential

```
ICredential credential = LoadCredentialFromSomewhere();
var client = new AgentsClientBuilder
{
    TokenAccessMethod = credential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync 
}.Build();
```

#### From a path to a JSON file

```
var client = new AgentsClientBuilder
{
    CredentialsPath = "/path/to/serviceaccount.json"
}.Build();
```

#### From JSON you already have as a string

```
string json = LoadJsonFromSomewhere();
var client = new AgentsClientBuilder
{
    JsonCredentials = json
}.Build();
```